# How do I reshape this DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df_sale` in Python that I want to reshape, count the sum across the `price` column and add a new coloumn `total`. Below is the `df_sale`:

```
b_no  a_id  price  c_id
120   24     50     2
120   56     100    2
120   90     25     2
120   45     20     2
231   89     55     3
231   45     20     3
231   10     250    3
```

Excepted Output after reshaping:

```
b_no  a_id_1  a_id_2  a_id_3  a_id_4  total  c_id
120   24      56      90      45      195    2
231   89      45      10      0       325    3
```

What I have tried so far is use the `sum()` on `df_sale['price']` separately for `120` and `231`. I do not understand how should I reshape the data, add new column headers and get the total without being computationally inefficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the cleanest method (at all), but it gets the outcome you want:

```
reshaped_df = (df.groupby('b_no')[['price', 'c_id']]
               .first()
               .join(df.groupby('b_no')['a_id']
                     .apply(list)
                     .apply(pd.Series)
                     .add_prefix('a_id_'))
               .drop('price',1)
               .join(df.groupby('b_no')['price'].sum().to_frame('total'))
               .fillna(0))


>>> reshaped_df
      c_id  a_id_0  a_id_1  a_id_2  a_id_3  total
b_no                                             
120      2    24.0    56.0    90.0    45.0    195
231      3    89.0    45.0    10.0     0.0    325
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like charm. Amazing how I still have a long way to go to write codes like you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this grouping by `b_no` and `c_id`, summing `total`, and flattening `a_id`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"b_no":  [120,120,120,120,231,231, 231],
     "a_id":  [24,56,90,45,89,45,10],
     "price": [50,100,25,20,55,20,250],
     "c_id":  [2,2,2,2,3,3,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df.groupby(['b_no', 'c_id'])['a_id'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('a_id_').fillna(0)

df2["total"] = df.groupby(['b_no', 'c_id'])['price'].sum()
```

```
print(df2)

           a_id_0  a_id_1  a_id_2  a_id_3  total
b_no c_id                                       
120  2       24.0    56.0    90.0    45.0    195
231  3       89.0    45.0    10.0     0.0    325
```